# Android : Not able to select item in MultiAutoCompleteTextView added in Dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, multiautocompletetextview

I am having `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` in custom dialog.
Added adapter to `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` successfully.
`MultiAutoCompleteTextView` gives suggestions but not able to select item from suggestion list.

Dialog xml contains :

```
    <MultiAutoCompleteTextView
             android:id="@+id/edt_ids"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img_email"
             android:layout_centerVertical="true"
             android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
             android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_add_contacts"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_email"
             android:background="@null"
             android:gravity="top|left"
             android:hint="@string/share_email_hint"
             android:inputType="textMultiLine|textEmailAddress"
             android:maxLines="6"
             android:minLines="1"
             android:paddingLeft="5dp"
             android:scrollbars="vertical"
             android:singleLine="false"
             android:textColor="@color/black"
             android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color_light_gray"
             android:textSize="@dimen/header_size" >

              <requestFocus />
    </MultiAutoCompleteTextView>
```

**Dailog in Activity :**

```
 MultiAutoCompleteTextView emailIdsEdt;
    emailIdsEdt = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) ratingDialog.findViewById(R.id.edt_ids);
    emailIdsEdt.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                        (Home.this, R.layout.custom_auto_email, contactEmails);
    emailIdsEdt.setThreshold(1);
    emailIdsEdt.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Please help me with this one.
Thanks in advance